# Python subprocess shell 'while loop'

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have to use a shell script to wait for a device to be ready. This should work using the `while [ ! -d "/dir1/" ];` statement. 
But when I combine it with Pythons subprocess it doesn't work. To figure out the problem I tried a simple counting loop and it's not working either. Somehow the variable is not assigned. What's missing?

```py
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(["i=0; while [ $i -lt 5 ]; do i=`expr $i + 1` echo $i; sleep 1; done"], shell=True)
0
0
0
```

Comment: It works for me, gives output ```1```

Comment: What says 1? I have this behaviour... https://onlinegdb.com/B1YZ12jUB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pffff, I missed a ';' behind the `` i=`...` `` expression... :-(